# how to import list from other module in python if module name starts with a number

Tags: python

i am using eclipse with python. i want to import a list from another module in directory (Jan23) file (3.py) list(color)

```
from Jan23.3 import color
```

gives me

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

why?

Comment: Short answer: Module names can't start with a digit; use [a legal identifier as the module name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) if you want to be able to use it normally: "Within the ASCII range (U+0001..U+007F), the valid characters for identifiers are the same as in Python 2.x: the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, *except for the first character*, the digits 0 through 9." (emphasis added)

Comment: thanks for the help. I will definitely read first and ask questions later from now on :)